# Fading div in/out by clicking another div

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

I have a `div` element. By clicking it, it shows the other `div` used for login. Login `div` contains another `div`, `login-close`, which will hide the login div on click. I am struggling with the required jQuery. Here is what I have so far:

```
<html>
    <div class="member"></div> 
    <div class="login">
        <div class="login-close"></div>
    </div>
</html>
```

```css
.member {
    width: 80px;
    height: 67px;
    float: right;
    background-color: #4CA502;
    background-image: url(../images/social-icon/dark/member.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
.login {
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    background: #090;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 87px;
}
.login-close {
    background: #093;
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    top: -30px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".member").click(function () {
        $(this).next(".login").fadeIn(1000);        
    });
    $(".login-close").click(function () {
        $(this).next(".login").fadeOut(1000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The close button is a descendant of the login div so `.next('.login')` won't work, instead you can use `.closest('.login')` to find the ancestor `.login` element

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".member").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".login").fadeIn(1000);

  });
  $(".login-close").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".login").fadeOut(1000);
    //or use .parent() since these are direct parent-child elements
    //$(this).parent().fadeOut(1000);
  });
});
```

```css
.member {
  width: 80px;
  height: 67px;
  float: right;
  background-color: #4CA502;
  background-image: url(../images/social-icon/dark/member.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
.login {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #090;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 87px;
}
.login-close {
  background: #093;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  top: -30px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="member"></div>
<div class="login">
  <div class="login-close"></div>
</div>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yatv89ww/)

Comment: simply is,did not  know make.Thank You!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".member").click(function () {
    $(this).next(".login").fadeIn(1000);        
  });
  $(".login-close").click(function () {
    $(".login").fadeOut(1000);
  });
});
```

Comment: Please explain what you change and why... Just cone is not a answer

Comment: happy to help you...and if you are satisfied with the answer you can accept it